# @Python - NameError: global name 'select' is not defined

Tags: python, select, paramiko

I used `import select` before calling the function that has select.

I used select as shown below:

```
rl, wl, xl = select.select([stdout.channel], [], [], 0.0)
```

Here `stdout.channel` is something I am reading from an SSH connection through paramiko.

Stack Trace:

```
File "C:\Code\Test.py", line 84, in Test

rl, wl, xl = select.select([stdout.channel], [], [], 0.0)
NameError: global name 'select' is not defined
```

Comment: You used `import select` *before* starting the program?  Shouldn't it be *in* the program?

Comment: @zondo I meant before I called the function. Making the edit to the question now.

Comment: it seems good to me, try restart your computer see it works or not

Comment: Can you show more of your code? If the file has `import select` at the start, then you shouldn't be getting this error. Also it might be worth including the stack trace.

Comment: Do you do the import in a different function? If you don't do it at the top-level module scope, then that would cause this error.

Comment: @babbageclunk When I meant I did it before the function, I did at top-module level scope

Comment: Try to produce a minimal piece of code that matches the structure of your code and still has the problem, and post it here in full. Without seeing more of your code it's hard to help you. From what you're saying it should work.

Comment: `from sqlalchemy.sql import select`

Answer (score 0):

Observations:

1. When running the python script from command line - works well. No such errors are brought up.
2. When running the same script using ECLIPSE, I see an error as stated above.

Solution:

I imported select by using:

```
import select as something
```

Now when I use it in my script, the error is gone.

```
rl, wl, xl = something.select([stdout.channel], [], [], 0.0)
```

Comment: When you do `import select as something`, the name `something` is bound in the scope, but the name `select` isn't - that's the problem.